# Can't use XSLT to produce HTML from XML file with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt

I have an XML file on disk (file scheme) which starts with the following declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="speisekarte.xsl"?>
<speisekarte>
    ...
</speisekarte>
```

`speisekarte.xsl` is an XSL stylesheet which generates HTML (version 4.01) from the XML.

This works fine on Mac OS X with Safari and Google Chrome (given the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option).

On Windows, it also works with Google Chrome (given the same option), but I can't get it to work with Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702. It always displays the XML tree, so it doesn't run the transformation.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="speisekarte.xsl"?>` instead (i.e. change `text/xml` to `text/xsl`)? Or does IE 8 display a bar with a security warning?

Comment: That's it - thanks. I was told not to use `type="text/xsl"` because it isn't officially registered as a MIME type. Thanks again!

Comment: I have moved the suggestion to an answer to allow solving the problem correctly on StackOverflow. As for the MIME type, some types on the web like `text/xsl` or `text/javascript` are well established in practice even if there are no official registrations or the official ones suggest different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="speisekarte.xsl"?>` instead of `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="speisekarte.xsl"?>`.